# Are there any known problems using QGIS on Mac OSX Mountain Lion?

Tags: qgis, osx

A few days ago Apple released a new version of the OSX (10.8) and I'm thinking about upgrading.

So, I was wondering if anyone had any problems with GIS applications (QGIS) and other similar software after the upgrade?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bproblem+%2Blion

Comment: To my knowledge, there has not yet been extensive testing of QGIS 1.8.0 or master branch under Mac OS X 10.8 by developers. It would be appreciated if any issues found by users were not only noted here, but also opened as tickets at [the QGIS project issue tracker](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any experience with OSX and Mac OSX Maverics using OSGeo?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75186/any-experience-with-osx-and-mac-osx-maverics-using-osgeo)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one, I'm afraid, from one of our students, who is missing all of the components of the raster menu, except for the ubiquitous raster calculator:

> After updating from OSX Lion to OSX Mountain lion (OSX Version 10.8.1), upon opening QGIS I get this message
>
> > "Unable to load GdalTools plugin.  The required "osgeo [python-gdal]" module is missing.  Install it and try again".
>
> When I check the plugins, it looks installed and the box is checked.  How do I resolve this issue?  I have no menu options for the Raster dropdown menu, making this practical undoable on this machine.'

Comment: Damien, upgrading from 10.6 or 10.7 to 10.8 will clear any Python modules you have in the site-packages for Python 2.6 or 2.7. You have to re-install all of your Python modules again. Not a very user-friendly decision by Apple, IHMO. If using the kyngchaos.com installers, like [GDAL 1.9 Complete](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks), just run them again.

Comment: Reinstalling the GDAL Complete frameworks from Kyngchaos.com is important for any OS change, QGIS upgrade, and has solved some plugin weirdness for me on occasion.