# Any experience with OSX and Mac OSX Maverics using OSGeo?

Tags: qgis, gdal, mapnik, tilemill, osx

There is a new Apple Release of OSX called Mavericks and my questions are:

- Will GDAL run?
- Will QGIS run?
- Will Tilemill run?
- Will Mapnik run?
- Also are there any known issues?

A similar question about [Mountain Lion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30741/are-there-any-known-problems-using-qgis-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion).

Comment: @Jason, I wrote GIS because it was not only about QGIS.

Comment: How could I edit the question to make it less "opinion-based"? I don't get it.

Comment: I don't think that this should necessarily have been closed as "opinion-based" but I certainly think that it is too broad to be re-opened.  I suggest reviewing [**What makes a good question?**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question) and then start by asking whether just one of these software products will run under this OS version.  Also, include what research you have already done to try and ascertain that.

Comment: Well I don't want to write one question for each application, that would spam this site too much. Also the reason I am asking these questions is because I haven't installed Mavericks yet and I don't want to do that until I know it's OK to do it. So what should I do?

Comment: Look at this one: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106036/what-under-documented-features-have-you-stumbled-upon-in-mavericks Should I state the question like that? Like "Have you found any issues with GIS applications on Mac after upgrading to Mavericks? State one application/issue in one answer"

Comment: My advice is still more or less the same.  I would start by asking four questions as four Questions.  The first would be "Has anyone successfully run GDAL under Apple Release of OSX called Mavericks?" and state at the outset that you are asking to determine whether you should try to.  You should also say that you have searched the Apple SE site unsuccessfully (if that is the case).  Personally, I would not state "one application/issue in one answer" but if I were to Answer I would either say "Yes, works fine" or "No, I had this issue".

Answer (score 1):

**QGIS 2.0.1**

Tried to start it up gave two errors:

First error

```
Couldn't load plugin openlayers_plugin due an error when calling its classFactory() method

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 204, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/Users/ustroetz/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/__init__.py", line 25, in classFactory
    from openlayers_plugin import OpenlayersPlugin
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/ustroetz/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/openlayers_plugin.py", line 35, in 
    from openlayers_ovwidget import OpenLayersOverviewWidget
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/ustroetz/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/openlayers_ovwidget.py", line 36, in 
    import bindogr
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/ustroetz/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/bindogr.py", line 1, in 
    from osgeo import ogr, osr
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named osgeo

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]


QGIS version:
2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, f738351

Python path: ['/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python', '/Users/ustroetz/.qgis2/python', '/Users/ustroetz/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Second error

```
Unable to load GdalTools plugin. 
The required "osgeo [python-gdal]" module is missing. 
Install it and try again.
```

QGIS started up fine. OpenLayers Plugin wasn't there anymore though.
After trying to reinstall the OpenLayers Plugin I code the following error:

```
The plugin depends on some components missing on your system. You need to install the following Python module in order to enable it: osgeo
```

After reinstalling GDAL everything worked like before. No more errors.

---

**GDAL**

no Problems so far, works fine

**Tilemill & Mapnik**

don't use them

Comment: Thanks! I heard form last update that it's good to reinstall GDAl etc from Kyngchaos after a major OS update. Did you do this?

Comment: @OskarKarlin Thanks for the hint. Reinstalled GDAL and it works like before.

Comment: You mean QGIS? Or GDAL? You said "no Problems so far, works fine" with GDAL

Comment: It didn't experience any problems with GDAL before reinstalling it. Though reinstalling GDAL fixed QGIS (QGIS uses GDAL).

Comment: @OskarKarlin One question (in this case product) per Question would have made the product being talked about here obvious. Trying to Answer multiple questions in a single Question invariably gets messy and GIS SE strives to provide clean Q&A.